# Prolog double period

Tags: prolog, logic

What does "`..`" mean in Prolog?

I have this code:

```
Goal=.. [GoalPredicate|Pos]
```

and I don't know what the "`..`" means

Comment: A tiny remark: Will `Goal` be called thereafter? That is, does `Goal` or `call(Goal)` appear a little later? Many such occurrences of `(=..)/2` can be replaced by `call/2`, `call/3`.

Comment: Yes it is, by call(Goal) three or four line later

Comment: Then you should use `call/N`! It is one of the most underestimated features we have. It supports clean higher order programming.  Put the relevant source including all occurences of the three variables into your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This operator is called "univ" and described in for instance the GNU Prolog Manual [here](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc83):

> **8.4.3  (=..)/2 - univ**
>
> Templates
>
> ```
> =..(+nonvar, ?list)
> =..(-nonvar, +list)
> ```
>
> Description
>
> Term `=..` List succeeds if List is a list whose head is the atom corresponding to the principal functor of Term and whose tail is a list of the arguments of Term.
>
> `=..` is a predefined infix operator (section 8.14.10).

Other good resources describing this operator:

- [PROLOG 12.1  More Useful Features of PROLOG](http://www.dontveter.com/basisofai/12.html)
- http://wwwcgi.rdg.ac.uk:8081/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/wsi14/poplog/prolog/ploghelp/univ